# How would checking if a value in a data structure equals NULL return a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am trying to load a hash table of node*(s)-

```
typedef struct node{
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    struct node* next;
}node;
```

(don't worry about length, it is defined in the file that calls this)

-into memory, but this:

```
//  make hash table
node* hashtable[729];

node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
node* cursor = NULL;
int bucket;
while(sscanf(dictionary,"%s",new_node->word) != 0)
{
    bucket = hash(new_node->word);

    cursor = hashtable[bucket];
    while(cursor->next != NULL)
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    cursor->next = new_node;
}
return true;
```

keeps turning up to be a segmentation fault (specifically the condition of the while loop). I am baffled, what is going on? Thank you in advance to any who helps! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Length is actually the first problem, you can't dynamically size an array in c, it has to be defined at compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: `hashtable` appears to be an array of uninitialised pointers.  You then try to dereference one of them.

Comment: Just launch it in a debugger — when segfault happens, you would see a backtrace, and you then can look at values in the code. This way you can easily find were is the problem.

Comment: It looks very odd that you only ever malloc 1 node structure. Each entry in your hashtable array is pointing to the same single node structure. I presume you should either: a) create array of node structures (not pointers), or b) malloc within the while() loop.

Comment: I put into gdb and found that it was on the "while(...)" line, but I did not know why so I asked this question.

Comment: You never initialized `next`, so `cursor->next` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Would setting `cursor->next` to NULL work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for each node that is going into your hash table. How's about something like the following:

```
/* make hash table */
node* hashtable[729];

/* initialise all buckets to NULL */
memset(hashtable, 0, sizeof(node*)*729);

node new_node;  /* Use a stack node for the temporary */
new_node.next = NULL;
node** cursor = NULL;
int bucket;
while(sscanf(dictionary,"%s",new_node.word) != 0)
{
  bucket = hash(new_node.word);

  cursor = &hashtable[bucket];
  while(*cursor != NULL)
  {
    cursor = &(*cursor)->next;
  }

  if ((*cursor = malloc(sizeof(node))) != NULL)
    /* Copy from temporary to hashed node. Assumes structure is 'flat' */
    **cursor = new_node;
  else {
    /* panic! */
  }
}
return true;
```

**Edit:**

I've refactored some code and produced a standalone example that compiles and runs, For simplicity, I've employed a totally bogus hash function and reduced the number of buckets to fit its output of 0-25. I've tried to split out the hashtable 'object' and started the effort to be a little more disciplined to avoid buffer overruns, etc.

For the traversal of the linked list of nodes in a bucket of the hashtable, I've included two versions--one that uses the node** (pointer to a pointer) and another that doesn't--in an attempt to demonstrate the use of the double star. Change the `#if 1` to `#if 0` to use the "single star" version.

I hope that, collectively, these changes help clarify (more than they obscure) the original purpose, although I apologise for the verboseness of the code that follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LENGTH 64

typedef struct node {
  char word[LENGTH+1];
  struct node * next;
} node;

typedef struct hashtable {
  node * table[26];
} hashtable;


/* The cleverest 'hashing' function in the world ever! */
int hash(const char * str) {
  if (str && str[0]) return tolower(str[0]) - 'a';
  return 0;
}

/* Allocate a new node and initialise it with the given word */
node * node_create(const char * word) {
  node * nd = NULL;
  if (word && (nd = malloc(sizeof(node)))) {
    strncpy(nd->word, word, sizeof(nd->word)-1);
    nd->word[sizeof(nd->word) - 1] = '\0';
    nd->next = NULL;
  }
  return nd;
}


/* Set all the buckets' pointers to NULL */
void hashtable_init(hashtable * ht) {
  if (ht) memset(ht, 0, sizeof(hashtable));
}

/* Place the given node into the hashtable, taking responsibility for it */
void hashtable_insert_node(hashtable * ht, node * nd) {
  if (ht && nd) {

#if 1 /* More succint version using node**  */

    /* Identify the bucket this node should go into */
    node ** cursor = ht->table + hash(nd->word);

    /* Append this node to this bucket's list of nodes */
    while (*cursor != NULL) cursor = &(*cursor)->next;

    *cursor = nd;

#else /* Version that avoids use of node**  */
    int bucket = hash(nd->word);

    /* Identify the bucket this node should go into */
    if (ht->table[bucket]) {
      node * cursor = ht->table[bucket];
      while (cursor->next) cursor = cursor->next;
      cursor->next = nd;
    } else {
      ht->table[bucket] = nd;
    }
#endif

    nd->next = NULL;  // Ensure the new node is the last in the list
  }
}

/* Free the contents of the given hashtable */
void hashtable_free_contents(hashtable * ht) {
  if (ht) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(ht->table)/sizeof(ht->table[0]); ++i) {
      node * cursor = ht->table[i];
      while (cursor != NULL) {
        node * next = cursor->next;
        free(cursor);
        cursor = next;
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Dump the contents of the given hashtable to stdout */
void hashtable_dump(const hashtable * ht) {
  if (ht) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(ht->table)/sizeof(ht->table[0]); ++i) {
      printf("Bucket %d:", i);
      node * cursor = ht->table[i];
      while (cursor != NULL) {
        printf(" %s", cursor->word);
        cursor = cursor->next;
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char dictionary[] = {
    "apples "
    "apricots "
    "oranges "
    "lemons "
    "bananas "
    "raspberries "
    "carrots "
    "tomatoes "
    "aubergines "
    "limes "
    "blueberries "
    "plums "
    "pears "
    "peaches "
    "pineapples "
    "tangerines "
    "kiwis "
    "passion_fruit "
    "strawberries "
  };

  hashtable ht;
  hashtable_init(&ht);

  char * p = dictionary;  /* Pointer for traversing the dictionary */

  node new_node;  /* Temporary node for storing word read from dictionary */
  new_node.next = NULL;

  int n; /* Number of bytes read from dictionary in sscanf call */
  char format[16];

  /* If a huge word is in the dictionary, guard against buffer overflow */
  snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds%%n", sizeof(new_node.word));

  while(sscanf(p, format, new_node.word, &n) == 1) {
    /* Insert (a copy of the) new node into hashtable */
    hashtable_insert_node(&ht, node_create(new_node.word));

    /* Move forwards through the dictionary */
    p += n;
  }

  hashtable_dump(&ht);

  hashtable_free_contents(&ht);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan! I am still a little new to programming (6 months of on and off experience) so please pardon me for asking.What does the node** do? I have heard of pointers, but is this a pointer to a pointer or is it just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Just allocate memory for each node of the hashtable and then dereference them.
i.e.

```
int i ;
for(i = 0; i < 729; ++i) {
    hashtable[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
    hashtable[i]->next = NULL ;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is right: each element in the hashtable array is a linked list of nodes. There needs to be a malloc per node being hashed, not a malloc per bucket in the hashtable.

Comment: Ideally, the hashtable's `ith` node should be initialized if `i` is the result of the hash function. So yes, this is not technically correct - It will allocate all the nodes of the table right from start. Also, if the hash function can generate a large range of values, it is ideal to go for a sparse array implementation.